# Referencing and running TensorFlow FSharp from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, f#, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run the example from https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharp-ai-tools from Visual Studio 2019 (community edition). I would like to use it in a .NET Framework application and to experiment in FSI, from Visual studio 2019 itself.
Has anybody had success with this library from within Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: If the correct answer to your question is `Yes`, it may be worth re-phrasing the question.